# MySQL migrate data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm attempting to move data from one table to another, as part of a restructure to the database architecture. I'm using PHPMyAdmin and MySQL to do so.

The SQL is meant to, for each `emergency_contacts.id`, move `e_c.id` and `e_c.activity_id` to `activities_emergency_contacts`, where the pair will form a composite key to link a contact with an activity.

The following SQL returns an error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()

BEGIN
    SET @cid = (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM `emergency_contacts`);
    SET @aid = (SELECT `activity_id` FROM `emergency_contacts` WHERE `id` = @cid);    

    WHILE @cid IS NOT NULL DO

        INSERT INTO activities_emergency_contacts (activity_id, contact_id) 
        VALUES (@aid, @cid);

        SET @cid = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM emergency_contacts WHERE @cid < id);
        SET @aid = (SELECT activity_id FROM emergency_contacts WHERE id = @cid);

    END WHILE;                
END;

CALL dowhile();
```

> **SQL query:**
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile() BEGIN  SET @cid = (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM
>   `emergency_contacts`)
>
> **MySQL said:**
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds  to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `''` at line 3

I have searched the MySQL specific documentation to try and find any issues with my `SET`, `WHILE`, `BEGIN/END`, `INSERT`, `CREATE` - just about every line. I'm unsure how to proceed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I missed a closing bracket inside the `WHILE` on `SELECT MIN (id)`, however I've fixed this and am still getting the exact same issue.

**EDIT:** The issue was that I was not using DELIMITER. Correct SQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
    SET @cid = (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM `emergency_contacts`);
    SET @aid = (SELECT `activity_id` FROM `emergency_contacts` WHERE `id` = @cid);    
    WHILE @cid IS NOT NULL DO
        INSERT INTO activities_emergency_contacts (activity_id, contact_id) VALUES (@aid, @cid);
        SET @cid = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM emergency_contacts WHERE @cid < id);
        SET @aid = (SELECT activity_id FROM emergency_contacts WHERE id = @cid);
    END WHILE;                
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL dowhile();
```

Comment: Missing ) after min(id

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you for pointing this out, however even after fixing that I'm still getting the exact same error. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: PHPMYADMIN usually has a delimiter set you may need to change this to compile your procedure.

Comment: @P.Salmon This worked! You should submit it as an answer so I can accept it.